# Conversion of Word/Excel/PPT for Web-viewing

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, ms-office, libreoffice, dynamic-image-generation

**I need inputs on how to do this process.**

1. Take in Word/Excel/PPT documents. These documents will be regularly updated and changed for company's internal use.
2. Display them on a webpage.

Initial Discussions are to convert OfficeFormats to JPEGs/PDFs for Display. 
What would be a recommended solution (need a program/not something like Office 365 or Google Docs)?

PS: The team is good at ASP.NET and using APIs.